# Arithmetic in Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I would like to validate with a regex those values:

```
3.5 inch - 4.0 inch
4.0 inch - 4.5 inch
4.5 inch - 5.0 inch
5.5 inch - 6.0 inch
More than 6.0 inch
Less than 3.5 inch
Unknown
```

I wrote the above regex for this already which is:

```
(^3\.5\sinch\s-\s4\.0\sinch$)|(^4\.0\sinch\s-\s4\.5\sinch$)|(^4\.5\sinch\s-\s5\.0\sinch$)|(^5\.5\sinch\s-\s6\.0\sinch$)|(^More\sthan\s6\.0\sinch|Less\sthan\s3\.5\sinch$)|(^Unknown$)
```

But I found out this is quite long. Is there any way to shorten the code for my condition?

Btw guys, the value should match only condition above. Any other value than that  is wrong eg.4.5 inch - 6.0 inch

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what is your final goal? Which language are you using?

Comment: Can you just explain a little bit more..

Comment: Hi, so basically I just wanted to shorten my code. If you can see there are some similarities between the values for my condition. If I use "or" expression, my code will match if I put "4.0 inch - 6.0 inch". I use https://regex101.com to create the code.

Comment: Why regex? Which tool or language do you want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a suggestion making the regex a bit shorter:

```
(^(?:(?:^[3-5].[05]\sinch\s-\s[4-6].[05])|(?:More\sthan\s6\.0|Less\sthan\s3.5))\sinch$)|(^Unknown$)
```

#### Explanation

- `(^ ... \sinch$)` Something finishing by  `sinch`.
- `(?:(?:^[3-5].[05]\sinch\s-\s[4-6].[05])` First non-matching group checking for numbers in the range [3.0, 6.5].
- `(?:More\sthan\s6\.0|Less\sthan\s3.5))\sinch$)` Second non-matching group checking for *More than 6.0* and *Less than 3.5*.
- `(^Unknown$)` Unknown case.

### [Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/S57lC0/2)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but if I put this value: 4.0 inch - 6.0 inch it's gonna be captured too which is wrong.

Comment: @AkbarArief If intervals are precise, you definitevely can't short your regex a lot: you can just factorize the final *inch*.

Comment: Thanks for your help bro. I really Appreciate it